# knockout compute function - Cannot read property 'price' of null

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to access a property of an object, I know the object exists (and has the property I need) as i can log it to the console.

However when i try and access it, it says Cannot read property 'price' of null.

I am a C# developer and little confused I must be doing something wrong but i do not know what? From my screenshot, you can see the object returned.

My code is below:

```
self.total = ko.computed(function(){
    var total = 0;      
    var selectedServerName = this.selectedServer();
    var selectedServerObject = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.server, function(server){
        console.log("server.name = " + server.name);
        console.log("selectedServerName = " + selectedServerName);
        var serverCompare = (server.name == this.selectedServer());
        console.log("serverCompare is " + serverCompare);
    }, this);

    var selectedOsName = this.selectedOs();
    var selectedOsObject = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.os, function(os){
        console.log("os.name = " + os.name);
        console.log("selectedOsName = " + selectedOsName);
        var osCompare = (os.name == this.selectedServer());
        console.log("osCompare is " + osCompare);
    }, this);

    total = total + selectedServerObject.price + selectedOsObject.price;

    return total;
},this);
```

**Update**

My updated fiddle is here: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/SMUSv/10/)

Thanks to d.raev it appears when the second log line is added `console.log(selectedServerObject.price`, the arrayFirst function starts being called with `selectedServer = undefined`.

```
server.name = DELL R210
selectedServerName = undefined
serverCompare is false
server.name = DELL R710
selectedServerName = undefined
serverCompare is false
server.name = DELL R720 Dual CPU
selectedServerName = undefined
serverCompare is false
os.name = Windows Standard
selectedOsName = undefined
osCompare is false
os.name = Windows Enterprise
selectedOsName = undefined
osCompare is false
os.name = CentOS Linux
selectedOsName = undefined
osCompare is false
os.name = Debian
selectedOsName = undefined
osCompare is false
1.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of null
```

The undefined value from the selectedOsName or selectedServerName is causing the total to fail, what is the reason they are being set as undefined?

Comment: The error for 'console.log(selectedServerObject.price)' implies that selectedServerObject is null. So maybe whatever context you have that line in the object has been changed.

Comment: `this.selectedServer()` keeps returning `undefined`. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: Please check current fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/SMUSv/5/, the `Object {name: "DELL R210", specification: "1 x 2.4GHz Quad Core CPU<br/>4GB RAM<br/>2 x 300GB SAS 15k", price: 100}` is logged to the console on line 205

Comment: @g18c I added example how to escape the error .. but I m not sure what should be the expected output for total.

Comment: @d.raev many thanks, the total should total a number of fields, you have hit the nail on the head though the real question is where is the undefined value coming from in the test method?

Comment: `selectedServer(self.server[0].name)` probably self.server is not difnied fist time you call selectedServer or the init is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script runs 2 times this function, adding a second Debug shows it more clear:

```
var selectedServerObject = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.server, function(server){
    console.log("server.name = " + server.name);
    console.log("selectedServer = " + this.selectedServer());
    return server.name ==  this.selectedServer();
}, this);
```

Output:

---

server.name = DELL R210
selectedServer = **undefined**
server.name = DELL R710
selectedServer = **undefined**
server.name = DELL R720 Dual CPU
selectedServer = **undefined**
**null**    (selectedServerObject)
...
server.name = DELL R210
selectedServer = DELL R210
Object {name: "DELL R210", specification: "1 x 2.4GHz Quad Core CPU 4GB RAM
2 x 300GB SAS 15k", price: 100}

---

Just add a check if selectedServerObject is set .. or find why it is called 2 times:

**example:**

```
if(selectedServerObject){
   total = total + selectedServerObject.price;
}
```

Comment: is ko.utils.arrayFirst not a utility that requires a function returning a bool to define when the object should be selected? http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html `Knockout provides ko.utils.arrayFirst that will execute a function against each item in our array and return the first item where the function evaluates to true`

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/2SAxR/2/ shows the suspicions of d.raev were correct :) I have created a trimmed down version of my original code, the description computed function is called when the selectedServer is undefined, causing everything to bomb out.

I have marked d.raev's reply as the answer as it found the underlying cause - would be nice to understand this knockoutjs behaviour for full closure.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: server">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="server" data-bind="attr: {value: sku}, checked: $root.selectedServer" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<p data-bind="text: selectedServer"></p>
<p data-bind="text: description"></p>

var serverOptions = [{
    name: "One",
    sku: 1000,
    specification: "yes",
    price: 100
}, {
    name: "Two",
    sku: 1001,
    specification: "hello",
    price: 200
}, {
    name: "Three",
    sku: 1002,
    specification: "wow",
    price: 300
}];

viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.server = serverOptions;
    self.selectedServer = ko.observable();
    self.description = ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedSku = this.selectedServer();
        if(typeof selectedSku == "undefined")
        {
            console.log("we are not fully bound, bombing out here...");
            return;
        }

        var found = ko.utils.arrayFirst(serverOptions, function (item) {
            var result = (item.sku == selectedSku);
            console.log("arrayFirst check => item.sku = " + item.sku + " selectedSku = " + selectedSku + ". result = " + result );
            return result;
        }, this);

        var textDescription = found.name + " - " + found.specification + " (" + found.price + ")";

        return textDescription;
    }, this);

    return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```